# Pick Pack And Ship doesn't fetch current row data when item is already picked

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have a customization that fetches the inventory description and image based on the selected row on the grid, when it's not yet picked it generate the correct description and image. but once the item is picked and the row turns into green text it doesnt fetch the data.

We tried using Field selecting, RowSelecting and Row Selected events to see if the current row value is changes yet is still doesnt work. Here are some of the codes we used.[image: event codes]

Comment: Besides giving a screenshot of the code, provide with text of your C# code